# COM+ dll component name is missing after adding it to Component Services

Tags: c#, wcf, dll, com+, component-services

I made a COM+ dll in C++ using an ATL project.  After the COM+ dll was added to the component services, it doesn't show the component name.  A link for the screen shot is given below,

https://www.flickr.com/photos/100661150@N07/16832241851/in/set-72157649061069133

I went through lot of tutorials but couldn't find a proper solution.  Is there a way to make the name appear because the name is needed in order to use the COM+ dll as an WCF.

Comment: *because the name is needed in order to use the COM+ dll as an WCF* - this makes zero sense. You cannot expose a COM+ component as a WCF service. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: There is COM+ dll which was written using C++.  I want expose those methods through a webservice.  whats the best way to do so?
i was following the below given tutorial in order to integrate the COM+ with a WCF,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978523.aspx

Comment: Is your problem about how to call methods on a com+ component from C#, or is your question about how to create a WCF service? They are two different questions, and based on your question I can't work out which question you are asking.

Comment: I want to use the COM+ dll in a webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name doesn't appear because it is not set in the .rgs file.  I have given a sample below,  change the code accordingly then it should show the component name

```
HKCR
{
    FEDTab = s 'RepDO Class'
{
    CLSID = s '{8949D894-3C9B-4430-8C66-7B2DC3DE7F2D}'
}
    DataObjects.RepDO = s 'RepDO Class'
{
    CLSID = s '{8949D894-3C9B-4430-8C66-7B2DC3DE7F2D}'
    CurVer = s 'FEDTab'
}
NoRemove CLSID
{
    ForceRemove {8949D894-3C9B-4430-8C66-7B2DC3DE7F2D} = s 'ProcessImage Class'
    {
        ProgID = s 'FEDTab'
        VersionIndependentProgID = s 'DataObjects.RepDO'
        ForceRemove Programmable
        InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
        {
            val ThreadingModel = s 'Both'
        }
        TypeLib = s '{C40C7D67-7D49-4291-B0C2-10DAA7824FD0}'
        Version = s '1.0'
    }
}
```

.rgs file could be found inside the ATL project folder